# flask+ftplib basic application

Tags: python, flask

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    address="someserver"
    global FTP
    ftp = FTP(address)
    ftp.login()
    return ftp.retrlines("LIST")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

...this gives me a following output:

```
226-Options: -l 226 1 matches total
```

The question is - why does not this print the output of retrlines and how do I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the [`ftplib.FTP`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) class says that `retrlines` takes an optional callback - if no callback is provided "The default callback prints the line to `sys.stdout`."  This means that the method `retrlines` does not actually *return* the data provided - it simply passes each line as it receives it to a callable that may be passed to it.  This leaves you with a couple of options:

1. Pass in a callable that can stores the results of being called multiple times:

   ```
   def fetchlines(line=None):
       if line is not None:
           # As long as we are called with a line
           # store the line in the array we added to this function
           fetchlines.lines.append(line)
       else:
           # When we are called without a line
           # we are retrieving the lines
           # Truncate the array after copying it
           # so we can re-use this function
           lines = fetchlines.lines[:]
           fetchlines.lines = []
           return lines

   fetchlines.lines = []

   @app.route("/")
   def hello():
       ftp = FTP("someaddress")
       ftp.login()
       ftp.dir(fetchlines)
       lines = fetchlines()
       return "<br>".join(lines)
   ```
2. Replace `sys.stdout` with a file-like object (from [`cStringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) for example) and then simply read the file afterwards:

   ```
   from cStringIO import StringIO
   from sys import stdout

   # Save a reference to stdout
   STANDARD_OUT = stdout

   @app.route("/")
   def hello():
       ftp = FTP("someaddress")
       ftp.login()

       # Change stdout to point to a file-like object rather than a terminal
       file_like = StringIO()
       stdout = file_like

       ftp.dir()

       # lines in this case will be a string, not a list
       lines = file_like.getvalue()

       stdout = STANDARD_OUT
       file_like.close()

       return lines
   ```

Neither of these techniques will hold up well under a lot of load - or even under any real concurrency.  There are ways to solve for that, but I'll leave that for another day.